# Why is there a difference in behavior between running in debug mode and stepping through code in wxpython GUI library in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, wxpython

Below snippet is cut down version of code I am dealing with.
It will behave differently when I run it in debug mode but behaves as I would expect when I step through debug mode.

environment:
Windows 10
PyCharm: 2022.2.4
Python: 3.10.8
wx.python lib: 4.2.0

```
import wx


class AddBoard(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.archive_board_cost = 0 
        self.archive_board_width, self.archive_board_height = [0, 0] 

        self.InitUI()
        self.onRadioButton()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.onRadioButton, self.archive_radial)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.onRadioButton, self.new_radial)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOK, self.ok_button)

    def InitUI(self):
        frame_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_panel_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        labels_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        archive_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        new_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.main_panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.label_width = wx.StaticText(self.main_panel, label='width', size=wx.Size(60, -1))
        self.label_height = wx.StaticText(self.main_panel, label='height', size=wx.Size(60, -1))
        self.label_cost = wx.StaticText(self.main_panel, label='cost', size=wx.Size(60, -1))

        labels_box.Add((66, 0), 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        labels_box.Add(self.label_width, 0, wx.ALL, 3)
        labels_box.Add(self.label_height, 0, wx.ALL, 3)
        labels_box.Add(self.label_cost, 0, wx.ALL, 3)

        self.archive_radial = wx.RadioButton(self.main_panel, label='archive', size=wx.Size(60, -1))
        self.archive_radial.SetValue(True)
        self.archive_width = wx.StaticText(self.main_panel, label=str(self.archive_board_width), size=wx.Size(60, -1))
        self.archive_height = wx.StaticText(self.main_panel, label=str(self.archive_board_height), size=wx.Size(60, -1))
        self.archive_cost = wx.StaticText(self.main_panel, label=str(self.archive_board_cost), size=wx.Size(60, -1))

        archive_box.Add(self.archive_radial, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)
        archive_box.Add(self.archive_width, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)
        archive_box.Add(self.archive_height, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)
        archive_box.Add(self.archive_cost, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)

        self.new_radial = wx.RadioButton(self.main_panel, label='new', size=wx.Size(60, -1))
        self.new_radial.SetValue(False)
        self.new_width = wx.TextCtrl(self.main_panel, value='0', size=wx.Size(60, -1),
                                     validator=IntValidator())
        self.new_height = wx.TextCtrl(self.main_panel, value='0', size=wx.Size(60, -1),
                                      validator=IntValidator())
        self.new_cost = wx.TextCtrl(self.main_panel, value='0', size=wx.Size(60, -1),
                                    validator=FloatValidator())

        new_box.Add(self.new_radial, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)
        new_box.Add(self.new_width, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)
        new_box.Add(self.new_height, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)
        new_box.Add(self.new_cost, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)

        self.standard_buttons = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.ok_button = wx.Button(self.main_panel, wx.ID_OK)
        self.cancel_button = wx.Button(self.main_panel, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        self.standard_buttons.AddButton(self.ok_button)
        self.standard_buttons.AddButton(self.cancel_button)
        self.standard_buttons.Realize()

        main_panel_box.Add(labels_box, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        main_panel_box.Add(archive_box, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        main_panel_box.Add(new_box, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        main_panel_box.Add((0, 20), 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        main_panel_box.Add(self.standard_buttons, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 3)

        self.main_panel.SetSizer(main_panel_box)
        self.main_panel.Layout()

        frame_box.Add(self.main_panel, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(frame_box)
        self.Fit()

    def onRadioButton(self, evt=None):
        self.DisableText()
        if self.archive_radial.GetValue():
            self.archive_width.Enable()
            self.archive_height.Enable()
            self.archive_cost.Enable()
        else:
            self.new_width.Enable()
            self.new_height.Enable()
            self.new_cost.Enable()

        self.CheckAllValues()
        self.Layout()

    def DisableText(self):
        self.archive_width.Enable(False)
        self.archive_height.Enable(False)
        self.archive_cost.Enable(False)

        self.new_width.Enable(False)
        self.new_height.Enable(False)
        self.new_cost.Enable(False)

    def CheckArchiveValues(self):
        colour = (255, 193, 193, 255)
        flag = True
        if self.archive_board_width <= 0:
            self.archive_width.SetBackgroundColour(colour)
            flag = False
        if self.archive_board_height <= 0:
            self.archive_height.SetBackgroundColour(colour)
            flag = False
        if self.archive_board_cost <= 0:
            self.archive_cost.SetBackgroundColour(colour)
            flag = False
        return flag

    def CheckAllValues(self):
        # refresh relevant values
        self.ClearChecks()
        if self.archive_radial.GetValue():
            return self.CheckArchiveValues()
        else:
            return all([self.new_width.Validate(), self.new_height.Validate(), self.new_cost.Validate()])

    def onOK(self, evt=None):
        if not self.CheckAllValues():
            self.Layout()
            return
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)

    def ClearChecks(self):
        self.ClearWidget(self.archive_width)
        self.ClearWidget(self.archive_height)
        self.ClearWidget(self.archive_cost)
        self.ClearWidget(self.new_width)
        self.ClearWidget(self.new_height)
        self.ClearWidget(self.new_cost)
        self.Layout()

    @staticmethod
    def ClearWidget(widget):
        colour = wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW)
        state = widget.IsEnabled()
        widget.Enable(True)
        widget.SetBackgroundColour(colour)
        widget.Enable(state)


class IntValidator(wx.Validator):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Validator.__init__(self)

    def Clone(self):
        return IntValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        ctrl = self.GetWindow()
        text = ctrl.GetValue()

        try:
            if int(text) <= 0:
                # wx.MessageBox("Positive integers only.", "Error")
                ctrl.SetBackgroundColour((255, 193, 193, 255))
                ctrl.SetFocus()
                ctrl.Refresh()
                return False

        except ValueError:
            # wx.MessageBox("Positive integers only.", "Error")
            ctrl.SetBackgroundColour((255, 193, 193, 255))
            ctrl.SetFocus()
            ctrl.Refresh()
            return False

        ctrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW))
        ctrl.Refresh()
        return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True  # Not used

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True  # Not used


class FloatValidator(wx.Validator):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Validator.__init__(self)

    def Clone(self):
        return FloatValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        ctrl = self.GetWindow()
        text = ctrl.GetValue()

        try:
            if float(text) <= 0:
                # wx.MessageBox("Positive numbers only.", "Error")
                ctrl.SetBackgroundColour((255, 193, 193, 255))
                ctrl.SetFocus()
                ctrl.Refresh()
                return False

        except ValueError:
            # wx.MessageBox("Positive numbers only.", "Error")
            ctrl.SetBackgroundColour((255, 193, 193, 255))
            ctrl.SetFocus()
            ctrl.Refresh()
            return False

        ctrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW))
        ctrl.Refresh()
        return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True  # Not used

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True  # Not used


def main():
    app = MainApp()
    app.MainLoop()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        dialog = AddBoard(self)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            pass


class MainApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        main_window = MainWindow(None)
        main_window.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

WHEN RUN IN DEBUG MODE:

Expected behaviour:
When line is selected with radio button: it should be checked and fail (since values are 0) but other line should be reset back to neutral.

Actual behaviour:
When snippet starts it will show 'archive' line as red (correct behaviour);
when swapped to 'new' line it will clear archive line to neutral and change 'new' line to red (correct behaviour);
when swapped back to 'archive' line it will clear 'new' line but will not change archive line back to red. (INCORRECT behaviour)

WHEN STEPPED THROUGH: (break point set to first line of method: 'onRadioButton':
(line 84) self.DisableText())

behaves as: 'Expected behaviour' above

comment:
This is first time I have encountered discrepancy between running debug mode/run mode and stepping through code. To my small brain it should behave EXACTLY the same.
Please confirm if this error happens in other IDE environments and or other python/wxpython versions. My last resort is to try package it into EXE file and test it in final environment but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using wxPython there are some things that you are not going to be able to do from inside of an event. some examples are calling "Refresh" or "Layout". How this is handled is by using "wx.CallAfter" and calling a function that will run the code that you need to have run outside of an event.

Debugging mode might change the default behavior of this. The reason why is when an event takes place it is going to come into wx via a Windows event callback. You do NOT want to stall the callback. It needs to return as fast as possible. This is the the reason why Refresh and Layout don't work from inside of an event because they can have long execution times. Breakpoints in debugging mode would cause issues so when in debugging mode wx probably passes the event call off to the main thread so the windows event callback can return as fast as possible.

Change the method "onRadioButton" to the code below and your script will run properly

```
def onRadioButton(self, evt=None):
    self.DisableText()
    if self.archive_radial.GetValue():
        self.archive_width.Enable()
        self.archive_height.Enable()
        self.archive_cost.Enable()
    else:
        self.new_width.Enable()
        self.new_height.Enable()
        self.new_cost.Enable()

    self.CheckAllValues()

    def _do():
        self.Layout()
        self.Refresh()

    wx.CallAfter(_do)
```